# Using kfp.dls.containerOp() to run multiple scripts on Kubeflow Pipelines

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I have been using the Kubeflow dsl container op command to run a python script on a custom for my Kubeflow pipeline. My configuration looks something like this :

```
def test_container_op():
    input_path = '/home/jovyan/'
    return dsl.ContainerOp(
        name='test container',
        image="<image name>",
        command=[
             'python', '/home/jovyan/test.py'
        ],
        file_outputs={
            'modeule-logs' : input_path + 'output.log' 
        }
    )
```

Now, I also want to run a bash script called `deploy.sh` within the same container. I haven't seen examples of that. Is there something like

```
command = [
'/bin/bash', '/home/jovyan/deploy.sh',
'python', '/home/jovyan/test.py'
]
```

Not sure if it's possible. Would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kubeflow job is just a Kubernetes job, thus you are limited with Kubernetes job entrypoint being a single command.
However you can still chain multiple commands into a single `sh` command:

```sh
sh -c "echo 'my first job' && echo 'my second job'"
```

So that you kubeflow command can be:

```py
command = [
'/bin/sh', '-c', '/home/jovyan/deploy.sh && python /home/jovyan/test.py'
]
```